# Kentico AMP - Kentico.AcceleratedMobilePages

Tags: kentico, accelerated-mobile-page

Does the Kentico.AcceleratedMobilePages add-on work with Kentico 11?

I installed it on a version 11 site and it throws the error below.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not load type 'CMS.DataEngine.AbstractInfoProvider`1' from assembly 'CMS.DataEngine, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=834b12a258f213f9'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'CMS.DataEngine.AbstractInfoProvider`1' from assembly 'CMS.DataEngine, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=834b12a258f213f9'.

Source Error: 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 

[TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'CMS.DataEngine.AbstractInfoProvider`1' from assembly 'CMS.DataEngine, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=834b12a258f213f9'.]
   Kentico.AcceleratedMobilePages.AmpFilterInfoProvider.GetAmpFilters() +0
   Kentico.AcceleratedMobilePages.CheckStateHelper.GetFilterState() +246
   Kentico.AcceleratedMobilePages.AmpFilter.OnFilterActivated(ResponseOutputFilter filter, String& finalHtml) +69
   CMS.OutputFilter.ResponseOutputFilter.FilterResponse(String finalHtml) +1266
   CMS.OutputFilter.ResponseOutputFilter.Close() +19
   System.Web.HttpWriter.FilterIntegrated(Boolean finalFiltering, IIS7WorkerRequest wr) +691
   System.Web.HttpResponse.FilterOutput() +117
   System.Web.CallFilterExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +61
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +91


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.2106.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the AbstractInfoProvider was removed and replaced with AbstractInfoProvider

So that module will need to be updated to work on 11.

https://devnet.kentico.com/documentation/api-changes/kentico-11/24447

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using Kentico.AccelratedMobilePages.1.0.3 which is supported in Kentco 10.

For Kentico 11 you need to install nuget package [Kentico.AcceleratedMobilePages.11.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Kentico.AcceleratedMobilePages/11.0.0)